# C++ list: copying a local list in a member list

Tags: c++, list, methods, std, member

in a method, I have a local variabile

```
std::list<proiezione> ora;
```

and a member variable of same type

```
std::list<proiezione> orb;
```

In my method I have

```
for (std::list<proiezione>::iterator it = ora.begin(); it != ora.end(); ++it)
    this->orb.push_back(*it);
```

but doesn't work!

this->mem is empty! why?

precisely:

```
class CMFCApplication4Doc : public CDocument
{
public:
std::map<CString, Esame> esami;
INT valore_lode;
proiezione pr;
std::list<proiezione> orb;
    void get_proiezione(FLOAT media_desiderata);
}

void CMFCApplication4Doc::get_proiezione(FLOAT   media_desiderata)
{
    std::list<proiezione> ora;
std::vector<CString> v_proiezione;
CString appoggio;
std::map<CString, Esame> es = esami;
calcola_proiezione(ora,&pr, es, media_desiderata,valore_lode);
for (std::list<proiezione>::iterator it = ora.begin(); it != ora.end(); ++it)
    this->orb.push_back(*it);
 ecc ecc (I don't touch orb anymore)

}
```

in debug mode I have "ora" with 25 elements, but "this->orb" with zero elements !

Comment: `mem = or;` should do judging by your title. `insert` if you actually want the list appended.

Comment: `or` is a reserved identifier per 2.12/2 (alternate spelling of `||`).

Comment: same behavior also changing name :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `std::copy` algorithm?

```
std::copy(tList.begin(), tList.end(), std::back_inserter(mem));
```

Or use copy-swap:

```
void MyClass::func(std::list<proiezione> tList)
{
    mem.swap(tList);
}
```

Or use the `assign` member:

```
mem.assign(tList.begin(), tList.end());
```

Or use the copy-assignment operator:

```
mem = tList;
```

Without seeing more code, it would be hard to tell you why it is empty.

Almost forgot (credit Casey with reminding me):  `or` is actually a reserved word, so you'll want to name your variable something else.

Comment: @volperossa What is the declaration and implementation of `calcola_proiezione`?

Comment: it's not the problem. I try also this with same results:
     `//calcola_proiezione(ora,&pr, es, media_desiderata,valore_lode);
 std::list<proiezione> test;
 proiezione nuova;
 test.push_back(nuova);
 for (std::list<proiezione>::iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
  this->orb.push_back(*it);`

results: orb.size()=0; test.size()=1

I think the problem is in declaration of orb; Should I initialize it to any value??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you have initialized `orb` (at least none that is shown in the code you have provided).  You do not need to initialize the list when you declare it because its default constructor does that.